# The wider bid-ask spread of in-the-forward American option

Tags: american-options, put-call-parity

Why is the bid-ask spread of a in-the-forward/money American call (put) much larger than the out-of-the-forward/money American put (call)? I suppose the answer to the same corresponding question regarding the European option would be the put-call parity which makes one equivalent to the other. But there are only inequality bounds for the American put and call, implying that the two are distinct instruments. I suppose my rationale for the European options does not hold. What is the true financial rationale?

**Edit:** We ought to look at the ratio of the bid-ask spread to the time value rather than the absolute value of the option. I need to review the question.

Comment: Larger as a percentage or larger in dollars or larger in what way?

Comment: @noob2: Good question. I edited and am reviewing the question.